# Sizing a UITableViewCell based on its contained UITextView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview

I'm working on an iOS app at the moment where I'm displaying lots of text in table view cells. The text in question is stored in an `NSAttributedString` can span an indefinite amount of lines and can have inline attachments such as images. The issue here is that I can't seem to get an accurate measure of a given cell's height to pass on to the table view. Is there a performant, simple way to calculate the height of an arbitrarily complex `NSAttributedString` contained in a `UITextView`?

Comment: Have you checked out: https://github.com/jerrykrinock/CategoriesObjC/tree/master/NS(Attributed)String%2BGeometrics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the `boundingRectWithSize:options:context:` method to find out its size.

```
[attributedString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(320.0f, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                               options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                               context:nil];
```

You can substitute the `320.0f` with whatever your expected width is for your text view.

Reference: [NSAttributedString UIKit Additions Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011688)

As a footnote, `NSString` has similar categories outlined [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

I had many failed attempts at this until I came across the free [Sensible TableView](http://sensiblecocoa.com) framework. The framework has what they call a TextViewCell that automatically resizes according to the text inside. Highly recommended.